# OpenDDS error transport_type=tcp is not registered :(

Tags: tcp, opendds

What are the possible reasons to get following error in openDDS? The application compiled without any errors. The ini file is used for configuration. When running the application I get following error.

TransportRegistry::create_inst :transport_type=tcp is not registered
TransportRegistry::load_transport_configuration: Unable to create transport instance in [transport/tcp1] section
ERROR: Service_Participant::load_configuration Unable to locate specified global transport config: config1
ERROR: Service_Participant::get_domain_participant_factory: load configuration() failed

Please help :(

Comment: Would help when you also would add the contents of your ini file

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to corrupted lib binaries from moving between windows and linux. Thanks Johnny for your reply.